# Is it always true that if $A \subsetneq B$ and $C \subsetneq D$, then $(A \cup C)\subsetneq (B \cup D)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it always true that if $A \subsetneq B$ and $C \subsetneq D$, then $(A \cup C)\subsetneq (B \cup D)$?

I can proof that $A \subseteq B$ and $C \subseteq D$, then $(A \cup C)\subseteq (B \cup D)$
but I am not sure about the proper subset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$A=\{1\}\subset B=\{1,2\}=D\supset C=\{2\}$$